# Calling servlet results in HTTP Status 404 "The requested resource is not available"

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

I have a servlet `register` in class `p1`. I have a JSP `jsp1.jsp`. I run JSP file and see it, but when I try to apply to the servlet, Tomcat shows an error:

> #### HTTP Status 404
>
> The requested resource (/omgtuk/Register) is not available.

Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/register")
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>omgtuk</display-name>
  
  
 <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>register</display-name>
    <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>p1.register</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>jsp1.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: The "not available" error usually happens because the application failed to initialize properly. Look at your logs during startup to see if there's an error in there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The requested resource (/omgtuk/Register) is not available.

This simply means that the servlet isn't listening on an URL pattern of `/Register`. In other words, you don't have a `@WebServlet("/Register")`.

In your particular case, you made a case mistake in the URL. URLs are case sensitive. You're calling `/Register`, but your servlet is listening on `/register`. Fix your form action accordingly.

So, it should **not** look like this:

```html
<form action="Register">
```

But it should look like this:

```html
<form action="register">
```

Or this, which is more robust in case you happen to move around JSPs when you're bored:

```html
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register">
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, please note that you registered the servlet via both a `@WebServlet` annotation on the class and a `<servlet>` entry in `web.xml`. This is not right. You should use the one or the other. The `@WebServlet` is the new way of registering servlets since Servlet 3.0 (Java EE 6) and the `<servlet>` is the old way of registering servlets.

Just get rid of the whole `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` in `web.xml`. You don't need to specify both. Make sure that you're reading up to date books/tutorials. Servlet 3.0 exist since December 2009 already.

Another detail is that `p1` is *not* a class, it's a package. I'd warmly recommend to invest a bit more time in learning basic Java before diving into Java EE.

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)