# Build.xml gives error while creating a war file using ant build

Tags: java, servlets, ibm-cloud

I download the bluemix starter application package for Java Liberty and created a jsp page to use javamail api and i created the a servlet that requests for parameters to jsp page and created the another class that transport  the mail using SMTP and i deploy this on bluemix.When i go to access it via internet the servlet is called but it does'nt respond anything may be it does'nt request my class that transport mesage so how can i solve this problem

and i set properties of smtp using contextparam in web.xml

Comment: are you able to deploy the servlet in to tomcat or any other server?? because you are getting compiler error

Comment: yes it will run properly on tomcat but gives error when i go to create war file for bluemix

Comment: Looks like you havent included the servlet jar in the compile classpath...

Comment: does it need to add servlet.jar in my app i hosted it on ibm bluemix

Comment: actully tomcat does'nt gives any error it will run fine on tomcat .but it gives error while creating a war file using build.xml for ibm bluemix

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the error{ requested resourse not avilable /emailsendingservlet.java} seems issue is with slash i.e try with emailsendingservlet.java instead of /emailsendingservlet.java.

When you add a slash to URL pattern then the container will look for a web application deployed with name 'emailsendingservlet'.Since this not there you will receive 404 error.

Below is the reference link:

[tomcat requested resource () is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063044/tomcat-requested-resource-is-not-available)

Comment: i remove that slash but it not works.@WebServlet("EmailSendingServlet") is my url pattern in my servlet and i  provide action="EmailSendingServlet" in my jsp page

Comment: when i create a new class path to  new Bin folder and i change the bin by replacing Bin in build.xml then it creates a war file but when i go to access it gives errors requested resourse not avilable /emailsendingservlet.java actually i guess that my class path has problem and my class files does not store in bin folder please help me

Comment: actually the problem might be in bin actully my .class file does not store in bin what is problem actually it stores in build/classes

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies in build.xml.you need to check if  build.xml  have a pointer to com.ibm.ws.javaee.servlet.[version].jar  in the path element which is defined in its classpath.

```
<path id="classpathDir">
<pathelement location="bin"/>
<pathelement location="lib/com.ibm.ws.javaee.servlet.3.0_1.0.1.jar"/>
</path>
```

Also,Check if the jar location is mentioned wrong or missing.

Comment: <path id="classpathDir">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <pathelement location="dep-jar/com.ibm.ws.javaee.jaxrs.1.1_1.0.1.jar"/> can i override the code you provided with this code  
    </path>

Comment: please help me what is problem

Comment: [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
    [javac] 1 warning what is this error means

Comment: now i created a war file but when i access it from bluemix then it gives error like requested resourse not avilable /emailsendingservlet.java

Comment: please help me the project still work fine with tomact but not work on ibm bluemix

Comment: for the latest error "requested resource not available" please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978877/calling-servlet-results-in-the-requested-resource-is-not-available

Comment: Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /EmailSendingServlet this erroe gives when i hit submit button